# Time left on an ESTA

Tags: usa, transit, esta, uk-citizens

I am a UK citizen with an ESTA valid until August 2019, I'm flying into the US in June 2019, then driving into Canada for 2 weeks, and then back to the US for another week.

Will there be any problems about the time left on the ESTA?

Comment: Are you concerned about your ESTA expiring, or about the 90 days you receive under the VWP?

Comment: ESTA is only used to get you on a plane or on a ship travelling to the US port of entry. Not for land travel.

Answer (score 6):

**No**, you'll be fine.  From the CBP website:

> *Do travelers need to update their travel authorization if it will expire before they depart from the United States?*
>
> No, An ESTA is only required to be valid on the day you enter the United States. The ESTA does not need to be valid for the entire time a traveler is in the U.S. If the ESTA expires while you are in the U.S., it will not affect your admissibility or the amount of time you are permitted to remain in the U.S.

[https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1223/~/does-my-esta-need-to-be-valid-for-my-entire-stay-in-the-united-states%3F](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1223/%7E/does-my-esta-need-to-be-valid-for-my-entire-stay-in-the-united-states%3F)

Comment: Plus if driving back to USA from Canada you don't need an ESTA